# ubuntu make install error

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, ppa, ubuntu-make

I have istallation for ubuntu make , followed the document [ubuntu make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)

**sudo apt-get update**  the following error some packages `W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/adt-raring/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/adt-raring/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is unrelated to installing ubuntu-make. Just continue with 'sudo apt install ubuntu-make'

To get rid of the error, you will have to remove the linuxgndu ppa by deleting the relevant ,list file from /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: linuxgndu ppa not founded this file  !!

Comment: What are the content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d ?

Comment: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/adt-raring/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/adt-raring/ubuntu xenial main

Comment: ` sudo apt install ubuntu-make
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    ubuntu-make is already the newest version (16.11.1~xenial1).
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
`

Comment: So ubuntu-make (umake) is installed. To get rid of the other error, you have to remove those lines refering to ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/adt-raring/ubuntu. The ppa was last updated in 2014, so it looks uotdated.